# GREP for multiple strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I have an url.txt I need check them and grep some data.

url.txt

```
domain.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
.....
```

Urls have in source this patterns:(mostly)

```
"web=pattern1"
"net=pattern2"
"office=pattern3"
```

I need this output:

```
domain.com: pattern1,pattern2,pattern3
domain2.com: pattern1,pattern2,pattern3
```

If there is no a pattern:

```
domain.com: pattern1,zero,pattern3
domain2.com: pattern1,pattern2,zero
```

Comment: Huh? You say "all sites have in source these patterns" yet the examples you list do not have those patterns. You say "all sites have in source these patterns" then you tell us what to do "if there is no a pattern". You contradict yourself. Please correct your question before you get downvoted or closed.

Comment: thanks fixed. "Urls have in source this patterns:(mostly)"

Comment: Please clarify the problem. Wikipedia says URLs are of this form: `scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id`

Comment: How do you tie any particular **pattern** to any particular **domain??**. Solving the problem is easy, but I don't understand the logic you are using.

Comment: wget -q www.domain.com -O - | grep -o -E -m 1 '"web=([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'=' -f2  I can not for multiple url and multiple pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this will extract the information that you want:

```
while read -r domain
do
    get -q "$domain" -O - | awk -F= -v RS='["#]' -v "d=$domain" -v web=zero -v net=zero -v office=zero '$1=="web"{web=$2} $1=="net" {net=$2} $1=="office"{office=$2} END{printf "%s: %s,%s,%s\n",d,web,net,office}'
done <urls.txt
```

#### How it works

The above loops over all the domains in `urls.txt`.  The new part is extracting the patterns from the output of `wget`.  That is done with this `awk` command:

```
awk -F= -v RS='["#]' -v "d=$domain" -v web=zero -v net=zero -v office=zero '$1=="web"{web=$2} $1=="net" {net=$2} $1=="office"{office=$2} END{printf "%s: %s,%s,%s\n",d,web,net,office}'
```

Taking the `awk` script a piece at a time:

- -F= -v RS='["#]'

  `awk` divides input into records.  Here, we set the record separator, `RS`, to a regular expression of either `"` or `#`.  This will mean that the text that you are looking for, such as `"web=yes"`, will appear as a complete record.

  `awk` further divides records into fields.  We set the field separator to an equal sign.  This way, the name that you are looking, such as `web`, appears as the first field and the value, such as `pattern`, is the second field.
- `-v "d=$domain"`

  The value of `domain` is saved in variable `d` for the final printout.
- `-v web=zero -v net=zero -v office=zero`

  This initializes are variables to their default values.  If the variable is not found in the `wget` output, then this is what will print.
- `$1=="web"{web=$2} $1=="net" {net=$2} $1=="office"{office=$2}`

  If `web`, `net`, or `office` is found as the first field of a record, then the second field is assigned to the appropriate variable.
- `END{printf "%s: %s,%s,%s\n",d,web,net,office}`

  When we have finished reading the `wget` output, this prints the results.

#### Demonstration of `awk` code with dummy input

```
$ domain=www.domain.com
$ echo 'abc "web=pattern1" def "net=pattern2" hij "office=pattern3" <end>'| awk -F= -v RS='["#]' -v "d=$domain" -v web=zero -v net=zero -v office=zero '$1=="web"{web=$2} $1=="net" {net=$2} $1=="office"{office=$2} END{printf "%s: %s,%s,%s\n",d,web,net,office}'
www.domain.com: pattern1,pattern2,pattern3
```

As a demonstration of a missing field, let's remove `net`:

```
$ domain=www.domain.com
$ echo 'abc "web=pattern1" def "office=pattern3" <end>'| awk -F= -v RS='["#]' -v "d=$domain" -v web=zero -v net=zero -v office=zero '$1=="web"{web=$2} $1=="net" {net=$2} $1=="office"{office=$2} END{printf "%s: %s,%s,%s\n",d,web,net,office}'
www.domain.com: pattern1,zero,pattern3
```